# how to set results per page limit in a category page in drupal?

Tags: drupal

I'm trying to set the amount of results returned in a category page in Drupal and cannot find where to do that.

This isn't a "view" so I don't set it there, rather, this is a category/% page, the default Drupal taxonomy listing page. Currently it's returning 10 per page and I need it at 5

I've tried theme_pager() that looks like I can set the $limit but it's not having an affect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Taxonomy module uses the `default_nodes_main` variable for the number of items to show.  This is the same variable hat is used for the number of items to show on the front page.  In Drupal7, you can set this value at `admin/config/system/site-information` configuration page.